# jsp php json communication

Tags: php, json, jsp

I have Json response from my database . I am using Php for this which can be viewed over [here](http://midsweden.gofreeserve.com/proj/androidj.php?identifier=123) . In this  we can search the record  from identifier  value like identifier =123  .  Is that possible to to show this response in the Jsp page . like when i put the identifier value in the text box of jsp page ,it can give the response from that database

Comment: what do you mean by "put the query string in the text box"? what text box?

Comment: @confiq  i mean when when i give 123 in the textbox of the jsp page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the PHP response does not have the [access control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control) headers which would allow crossdomain access by JS/Ajax, you would need to handle this fully at the server side.

Use [`java.net.URL`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) to get the PHP response as an `InputStream`. Use a JSON (de)serializer like [Google Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to convert the JSON string to an fullworthy Javabean. You can do this in a [servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info). Finally store this Javabean in the request scope and let JSP display it.